# I want to download a pdf file with data in two columns using table in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

I was retrieve the 4 data's in one array. Use those data i want printed in PDF

like ,

```
col1   col2
----------
 1      2
 3      4
etc    etc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the forum and read up on the help centre to find out how to ask a question. We are here to help troubleshoot your code. Please update your question with what you have done and someone can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

use this [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/tree/4bd49041a085c10751c93e5a05266fdfce5b6b6b/doc)

[basic usage](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/4bd49041a085c10751c93e5a05266fdfce5b6b6b/doc/basic.md)

```
$html2pdf = new \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->writeHTML('<h1>HelloWorld</h1>This is my first test');
$html2pdf->output();
```